# Labelling SCONJ and ADP in sentence using SpaCy

Tags: nlp, spacy

I was trying to label the all SCONJ and ADPs present in the sentence. However I had difficulty in labelling sentence involving both SCONJ and ADP. I am not able to tag the words connected to ADP root word

Code Snippet:

#code for labeling all the words connected SCONJ

```
if token.dep_ in ["mark","advcl", "ccomp", "xcomp","advmod"] or token.head.dep_ in ["mark","advcl", "ccomp", "xcomp","advmod"] or any(child.dep_ in ["mark","advcl", "ccomp", "xcomp","advmod"] for child in token.children): <br>
            if labels and labels[-1] in ['SP', 'SP_START']: <br>
                labels.append('SP') <br>
            else: <br>
                labels.append('SP_START') <br>
```

#code for labeeling all the words connected ADP

```
if token.pos_=='ADP' or token.head.pos_=='ADP'or any(child.dep_ in ['ADP'] for child in token.children) : <br>
          if labels and labels[-1] in ['ADP', 'ADP_START']:
                labels.append('ADP') <br>
          else: <br>
                labels.append('ADP_START') <br>
```